# Generate secp256k1 ECC key pair with libsodium

Tags: elliptic-curves, libsodium

I'm new to crypto and I want to generate a key pair, in C, which would be the equivalent of `openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -out ec-priv.pem`.

I love libsodium API but I can't find how (if ever) to generate a key pair that is an EC key. I was expecting to get a 32-byte private key, and a 64 byte (+0x04) public key.

Is it something that is not offered by the high-level libsodium API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question has been asked on the GitHub, too:

> Is there some way with sodium/libsodium to make all crypto_sign_* methods use SECp256k1?

And the answer was given as

> **No, there isn't, and there never will be.**
>
> Libsodium is an opinionated API. You get one good algorithm for every use case. Fewer knobs and levers + more secure constructions = less crypto vulns in software that consumes the API.
>
> For public key cryptography, you get ECDH and EdDSA over Curve25519. No Weierstrass or Koblitz curves.